# How to deploy and configure aspnetdb on a production server?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-2

I am developing a MVC 2 application that uses aspnetdb on my SQL Server 2008 detabase for forms authentication.
On my development machine I can configure the users, roles and permissions using my Website Administration Tool (WAT).
My question is how do I deploy this database to a production server and how do I configure it with users, roles and permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the framework folder you can find the scripts to generate all necessary tables and procedures for aspnet membership, after creating DB, you need to enter the records by generating insert scripts from your Dev DB.

Comment: Did you mean this folder? C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework? I tried looking in C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\SQL\en but I am not sure which script you mean.

Comment: @arame3333: yes this folder or Framework 2.0 folder, check *.sql files, all fileNames start with "install*" , you might look into the files to determine the execution sequence of files.Respective "Uninstall" scripts are also there.